# How to test github workflow without merging into master/main branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I am creating a new git workflow. And just like any other piece of code, I want to test it separately without having to merge it into master first.

This will also help if I have to make few corrections if something doesn't work in the workflow yaml.

Here is the mechanism that I am looking for:

1. main branch has .github folder which contains all workflows
2. I create a branch and add my workflow to .github folder
3. Now I should be able to see(somewhere on Github) workflows from my branch running
4. When I know that workflows are working fine, I merge my branch in master
5. Now under github 'Action' tab, new workflows will reflect

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could use [nekdos/act](https://github.com/nektos/act) to run your GitHub Actions locally

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am actually doing workflow testing all the name, as you can see [this test workflow workflow-level-notification](https://github.com/chenrui333/github-action-test/pull/33) is not merged into master branch (ie default branch), and I can still see the workflows [in the UI](https://github.com/chenrui333/github-action-test/actions/workflows/workflow-level-notification.yml).

Like GuiFalourd said, you can also use `act` to do the local testing as well. But working directly in the github repo is not that bad. (you can delete the workflow after)

Comment: If this works out, it'll be great. Let me check. 
I think I won't have to work with workflows too frequently so I'll keep `act` as a second option since there will be learning curve.

Comment: Update: The first approach worked out well. Github will show and execute workflows from any of the branches. When you delete the branch, new actions won't be triggered for those workflows that were in deleted branch. But you'll still see past executions though, which was fine in my case. Accepting this as an answer.

Comment: How is it working? Can you explain it? I have created a workflow file in a branch, created a PR, but in actions tab i see '.github/workflow/name-of-file.yml' and if I click o that, I see the commits of the branch

Comment: I think it only works for `pull_request` triggered workflows but not for any other triggers.

Comment: The "in the UI" link is broken.

Answer (score 21):

So, from the previous answers, seems that the (least-disrupting) solution is:

- Add the following trigger to the workflow

---

```
on:
  pull_request:
```

---

- Create a draft PR

The Workflow will then show-up under the `Actions` menu, it will immediately trigger, and it will again be triggered whenever new changes will be pushed to the branch you're using in the PR.

Answer (score 7):

You can run a `workflow_dispatch` workflow on your branch without merging into `master` with the `gh` cli (https://cli.github.com/):

`gh workflow run your-workflow-name --ref your-branch`

It also supports inputs: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow_run

I like to temporarily add `workflow_dispatch` to my workflow while testing it, then remove and put the real triggers in.

Answer (score 1):

I forked the repository in question into my own personal account and then tested the action there. Once I was sure the changes worked, I removed my fork and all the associated secrets.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to test non PR triggerd actions you can simply update your default branch temporarially, run the actions for test, then when you are done switch back.

Comment: Making temporary changes to the default branch is usually not advisable. If it is not a PR-triggered workflow, you are right that it is easy to test. In that case, maybe testing can be done on a topic branch as well.

Comment: Yes sometimes you are able, but if you are adding new workflows they must be present in the default branch before github will notice them. Switching default branch is only advisable if you know what you are doing, and probably not a good solution for a larger organization or more active project with many devs.